# How can I avoid 'A product is missing a field: google_product_category' warning in facebook microdata debugger tool?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-pixel, google-shopping-api

The tool 
https://business.facebook.com/ads/microdata/debug
gives me the warning

[image: A product is missing a field: google_product_category Without google_product_category information, your products may not appear the way you want them to in ads.]

Which OpenGraph tag can I use to fix the problem?

The HTML code like

```
<meta property="google:product:category" content="Pet Supplies"/>
    or
<meta property="google_product_category" content="Pet Supplies"/>
```

doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution

the right format is

```
<meta property="product:category" content="Apparel &amp; Accessories &gt; Clothing &gt; Dresses"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I can't believe this isn't better documented in Facebook's own site. They have a learn more button which doesn't even cover how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

this work too... I used it for multi-languages pages and works fine, just set the ids from google in google_product_category list

```
<meta property="product:category" content="233"/>
```